# Is it possible to send XOR'ed data to MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have XOR'ed media files.

I want to play them with [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) class. Is it possible to decrypt media flow on the fly (and be able to rewind them)?

Shortly, I want to have all functionality of `MediaPlayer` class for XOR'ed media files.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) may be too high level to accomplish this. I would suggest taking a look at [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html). If you read your file in using an [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) then you could XOR the data before feeding it to an AudioTrack instance. The only downfall to this approach is you will need to implement your own seek mechanism.